# Confused with chars in C++, issue memsetting

Tags: c++, c

I am confused with characters and their respective pointers in C++.

I have originally made a shell in C and I am trying to do it in C++. For some reason, I am getting a memory (coredump) when calling `memset()` and I am not sure why. I am confused on pointers.

For example, in C the following runs fine:

```c
int main() {
    char *valid[1024];
    while(1) {
        //eliding other code
        memset(valid, '\0', 1024);
    }
}
```

this works fine.

This is what I currently have in C++:

```cpp
int main () {
    char valid[1024];
    while(1){
        memset(valid,'\0',1024);
    }
}
```

Essentially the same code for `memset()`'ing, but it immediately crashes. All other functions of my program are commented out. Uncommeting `memset()` prevents the coredump.

In terms of pointers, I know that in C++ `char *valid[1024]` would be a pointer to a constant char array, right? Not sure why `*valid[1024]` works in C but not in C++? But in this case, I am running `char valid[1024]` in C++ so it is a modifiable array.

Comment: `char *valid[1024]` `!=` `char valid[1024]`

Comment: `char *valid[1024] would be a pointer to a constant char array right?` Not right. It would be 1024 pointers to chars.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do chars work the same way in C++ and C? I think that is what is confusing me the most. If so that means I accidentally got lucky in my C program.

Comment: You have not declared the variables the same way. - but the C++ program is OK except the endless loop. The C program writes `1024` `char`s to an array of pointers. 1/4 or 1/8 of the pointers will be unaffected by the `memset`.

Comment: It is not the call of `memset()` that is causing the problem.   The array has `1024` characters, and the call of `memset()` in your second code sample only sets those `1024` characters to zero.   The problem is in other code (that you haven't shown) in your program, which is presumably doing something untoward with a pointer and causing undefined behaviour.    It is quite common for undefined behaviour to result in a crash in another part of the program, such as - in your case - in a call of `memset()` that - in itself - does not cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you post the precise and complete code that crashes for you so that we can replicate the problem? Confirm that you can replicate the problem with all, and only, the code you post.

Comment: Hi, I just made a new file that only has the main function (no while loop), a declaration of char valid[1024] and the memset. This works fine on my Mac, but it DOES NOT work in the linux environment I am working in. I am not in charge of the linux environment so I am not sure what is the issue there. In any case thanks for your guy's help.

Comment: Is it the C++ code that's causing problems? It has Undefined Behavior. How do you know that it works on your Mac? Do you mean that one CPU core is at 100%?

Comment: @spontida `char valid[1024]; memset(valid, '\0', 1024);` works just fine on *all* platforms. Your problem is something else.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know that it works in my Mac because I made a new test file with just the main function and the declaration of the char array. Then I proceed to memset. It compiles and runs without any issue. However, this is not the case on the linux environment. Appreciate the response.

Comment: @spontida I don't understand how you can tell if the program you've shared with us works or not. How do you measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    char *valid[1024];
```

This is an array of 1024 `char*` -- it's not itself a buffer of characters.  This can point to other buffers but it is not itself a buffer.  It's perfectly legal, but very unlikely to actually be what was intended.

Your first memset actually only erases one quarter of this array (or less, depending on whether you're compiling as 32-bit or 64-bit); the rest is left uninitialised.  Also unlikely to be intended.

```
    char valid[1024];
```

This is an array of 1024 `char` -- which is a standard 1024-character buffer that can actually hold data.

The memset for this would actually work correctly.  Although you can make the compiler do the equivalent memset for you simply by using value initialisation:

```
    char valid[1024] = {};
```

(In C, you can also do this but you have to have a `0` inside the braces.)

So whatever is actually causing your crash, it is likely elsewhere.

Comment: In C++, an infinite loop without side-effects has UB, so even if the code looks ok, it's not.

Comment: Yes, the infinite loop is dumb and I assumed that was irrelevant to the real question, so I am not addressing that here.  Although it's true that some compilers aggressively try to optimise UB to the point of insanity.

Comment: Since the program has UB it's pointless to look for reasons for the crash elsewhere when there's already one possible reason presented. It may not be the only reason, but it's the one we see.

Comment: Thank you, the loop was just there to imply I had other stuff running. Upon removing everything and just leaving the initsiliation of char valid[1024=;  I found that it still causes an issue in the environment that I was working in. However, it works fine without any issues in my Mac. Thank you for clarifying my knowledge issues with the pointers.

Comment: As a quick follow up, what would be a use of char *valid[1024] in practical terms?

Comment: @spontida An array of pointers to data buffers or strings.  In C++, better to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: If you wanted an array of 1024 character-buffers, you could use that to hold pointers to them.  (Note though that by itself this doesn't create any buffers.)  You probably wouldn't actually do that, though, especially in C++ where there are better ways to do things.  Use `std::string` and `std::vector` rather than raw buffers and arrays where possible, it's harder to mess them up.  As I said, it is most likely that the original code was just a mistake.